# csvsimple and tabularray - fit table to page

Tags: tables, longtable, csv, tabularray, csvsimple

I have a code for creating a table from a CSV data file but the table size is very long.

I would like to automate the code so any table coming from any CSV file I use will fit into one page.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularray} %needs package ninecolors.sty
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,array,adjustbox}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

% ************* FONTS ********************************************
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{segoeui}[Path= ./fonts/,
Extension=.ttf,
BoldFont = segoeuib.ttf,
ItalicFont = segoeuii.ttf,
BoldItalicFont = segoeuiz.ttf]
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
% ****************************************************************

% ******************** GRAPHICS ************************
%
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./graphics/}}% to include all directories with images/graphics in it
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .jpg, .pdf, .ps}
% ******************************************************

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \caption[Short Caption for LoT]{Title of table}
        \label{table:tablename2}
        \vskip+0.5em
        \csvreader[%
        no head,
        separator=semicolon,
        centered tabularray={%  
            width=0.25\linewidth,
            rowsep = 4pt,
            colsep = 2pt,
            column{even} = {c, azure8!20, 0.5in},
            column{odd} = {c, 0.5in},
            column{1} = {c, 2.75in},        
            row{odd} = {font = \scriptsize},
            row{even} = {font = \scriptsize},       
            row{1} = {2em},
            row{2} = {font=\scriptsize\itshape},                
        },
        table head = {\hline[0.1em, black] \SetCell[c=5]{l}\large\bfseries TABLE HEAD\\\hline[0.1em,black]},
        %               table foot = {\hline[0.1em,black]},
        late after line = {\\\hline[0.15pt, black]},            
        late after first line = {\\\hline[0.15pt,black]},
        %   late after last line = {\\\hline[0.1em,black]},
        late after last line = \\\bottomrule,
        ]{data/data03.csv}{}{%
            \csvlinetotablerow%
        }
    \end{table} 


\end{document}
```

and the CSV file:

```
- alle befragten Studierenden -;;Studieneingang;Studienverlauf;gesamt

;;Anzahl;Anzahl;Anzahl

Anglistik;Bachelor;202;62;264

;Master;75;50;125

;gesamt;277;112;389

Computerlinguistik und Digital Humanities;Bachelor;12;5;17

;Master;28;27;55

;gesamt;40;32;72

Germanistik;Bachelor;320;105;425

;Master;139;62;201

;gesamt;459;167;626

Japanologie;Bachelor;70;42;112

;Master;21;13;34

;gesamt;91;55;146

Klassische Philologie;Bachelor;14;4;18

;Master;11;7;18

;gesamt;25;11;36

Medienwissenschaft;Bachelor;134;79;213

;Master;34;23;57

;gesamt;168;102;270

Phonetik;Master;6;4;10

;gesamt;6;4;10

Romanistik;Bachelor;56;27;83

;Master;35;23;58

;gesamt;91;50;141

Sinologie;Bachelor;20;9;29

;Master;4;4;8

;gesamt;24;13;37

Slavistik;Bachelor;12;4;16

;Master;7;2;9

;gesamt;19;6;25

gesamt;Bachelor;840;337;1177

;Master;360;215;575

;gesamt;1200;552;1752
```

I tried to use adjustbox but the code only gives me errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would not use `\adjustbox`, because this also scales the font. It is much better to keep the same font sizes and spacing for all the tables in your document and, if needed, just let the table flow to the next page in my opinion.

Comment: I used resizebox and it worked.